# VBA Passing variable to reference Named Ranges - object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to define name ranges and then reference them in a formula

The worksheet formula is this
 `=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS('CAR Dashboard.xlsm'!Q2_15_Video_Penetration,'CAR Dashboard.xlsm'!Q2_15_Module,B5),"")`

I passed variables in the formula and is returning an object defined error

`Sheets("QoQ Summary").Cells(5, 11).Formula = "=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS('CAR Dashboard.xlsm'!" & VPenName & ",'CAR Dashboard.xlsm'!" & ModuleName & ",B5,"")"""`

I'm not sure what's wrong with it. Can anybody help please? Thanks!

Below is the testing code. Please ignore undefined variables.

```
Sub test()
Dim ModuleName, VPenName, HPenName, CPenName, XPenName As String
   'Define  
   ModuleName = Sheets("Settings and Instruction").range("G1").Value
   VPenName = Sheets("Settings and Instruction").range("G2").Value

   ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=ModuleName, RefersToR1C1:= _
                "=OFFSET('" & rp & "'!R5C" & Module.Column & ",,,COUNTA('" & rp & "'!C" & Module.Column & "),)"

   ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=VPenName, RefersToR1C1:= _
                "=OFFSET('" & rp & "'!R5C" & VideoPen.Column & ",,,COUNTA('" & rp & "'!C" & VideoPen.Column & "),)"

Dim rng As range
'Set rng = range("'CAR Dashboard.xlsm'!" & VPenName)
'Application.Goto rng

 Sheets("QoQ Summary").Cells(5, 11).Formula = _
                 "=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS('CAR Dashboard.xlsm'!" & VPenName & ",'CAR Dashboard.xlsm'!" & ModuleName & ",B5,"")"""

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your closing bracket is in the wrong place, try this instead:

```
"=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS('CAR Dashboard.xlsm'!" & VPenName & ",'CAR Dashboard.xlsm'!" & ModuleName & ",B5,"""")"
```

Comment: I revised it as this, but still throws an error.. `"=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS('CAR Dashboard.xlsm'!" & VPenName & ",'CAR Dashboard.xlsm'!" & ModuleName & ",B5,"")"`

Comment: That's still not the same as my answer. You haven't escaped the final set of quotes.

Comment: the end needs to be `B5,"""")"`

Comment: Hi, thanks for being patient. I copied your answer in and it still throws an error...

Comment: what is in `G1` and `G2` (where the variables get their values from)

Comment: G1 and G2 are formulas concatenate strings from other ranges. G1 `=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM($C$3)," ","_")&"_"&SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(F1)," ","_")` and the result is `Q2_15_Module`, and G2 formula `=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM($C$3)," ","_")&"_"&SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(F2)," ","_")` , result `Q2_15_Video_Penetration`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74276/discussion-between-qshngv-and-s-o).